# AWS DeviceFarm ScheduleRun always returns AccessDeniedException in cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-device-farm, aws-policies

When I try to start a DeviceFarm run via CLI or API with an  IAM user, I'm always getting the following error:

`An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ScheduleRun operation: User: <user-arn> is not authorized to perform: devicefarm:ScheduleRun on resource: <upload-arn>`

It happens regardless of user permissions, even on a user who has the AdministratorAccess policy attached. Policy json:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The command I'm trying to run:

`aws devicefarm schedule-run --region=us-west-2 --project-arn=<project-arn> --test='type=APPIUM_PYTHON,testPackageArn=<package-arn>,testSpecArn=<spec-arn>'`

However I can still start the run manually via the web AWS console.

Comment: Have you attached the policy to the user you are trying to run the command as?

Comment: Yes, the policy I mentioned in the question is attached to the user I'm using. Also, I've tried attaching AWSDeviceFarmFullAccess policy, as well as giving the specific permission `"devicefarm:ScheduleRun"` using a custom policy. Result is always the same.

Comment: What happens when you run `aws sts get-caller-identity´ ?

Comment: @ChristophFischer it returns me my current user with userid, account, and arn